# How can I catch the Console log output within my own app in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin

I want to programmatically catch the console log within my own iOS app; I know I can redirect WriteLine but that's not enough; I need the 'native' output as well.

Comment: Have you been able to access logs ? If yes would you mind sharing your DllImports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the ASL Api from Apple (this a C API which is not bound in Xamarin.iOS, you need to write your own DllImports to the functions you're interested in).

Here is a description of how it's done in (Objective-)C: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/accessing-the-ios-system-log/